# Drop down my boostrap navbar in mobile view is always collapsed by default..how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code for navbar. It's working perfectly in desktop view but when it comes to mobile view the drop down is not functioning properly. What I might be doing wrong?

```
<nav class="fixed-top navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ftco_navbar bg-dark ftco-navbar-light" id="ftco-navbar">
  <div class="container">
  
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav" aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> Menu
    </button>
    <form action="#" class="searchform order-lg-last">
      
    </form>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>home"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/logo.png"></a>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Our Services
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Construction and Planning</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Architecting</a>
      
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">General Services</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interior Design</a>
      
    </div>
  </li>
        
        
        
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Which version bootstrap are you using? Show which files you are connecting in the head tag.

Comment: ...and explain exactly how the dropdown does not work.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov ...i am using boostrap 4...and i was trying make a dropdown in navbar ;..so when i click on "services" tab it should display the list of services.....its working as expected in desktop view...but in mobile view the same dropdown tab is not working..

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav
      class="fixed-top navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ftco_navbar bg-dark ftco-navbar-light"
      id="ftco-navbar"
    >
      <div class="container">
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#ftco-nav"
          aria-controls="ftco-nav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> Menu
        </button>
        <form action="#" class="searchform order-lg-last"></form>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>home"
              ><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/logo.png"
            /></a>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>about" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                id="navbarDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Our Services
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Construction and Planning</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Architecting</a>

                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">General Services</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interior Design</a>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>contact" class="nav-link"
                >Contact</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- Always remember to call the above files first before calling the
    bootstrap.min.js file -->
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you try adding these scripts. It seems to be working. Please let me know if this is working for you.